# Macro to move a row to another sheet but ignore formulas in new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am wondering if anyone can help me. I am using a macro to move information from one sheet to another once sold. The problem is that the new sheet has built-in formulas to auto-populate data when items are added. I was wondering if there is a way to still use the macro but have the row be moved over to the new sheet but have it ignore the formulas. Right now it moves the rows to the row after the last formula cell.

The Current code I am using is:

```
Sub Sold()
'Updated by Kutools for Excel 2017/8/28
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim K As Long
    I = Worksheets("Open Inventory").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    J = Worksheets("Sold").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If J = 1 Then
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sold").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
    End If
    Set xRg = Worksheets("Open Inventory").Range("H1:H" & I)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For K = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Sold" Then
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sold").Range("A" & J + 1)
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete
            If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Sold" Then
                K = K - 1
            End If
            J = J + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: For me, this code has issues here: `For K = 1 To xRg.Count`, after the first row, K goes from .Count to 0.

Comment: I suspect your issue lies in how you find the last row of data. [This reference](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba) describes several different ways, but you should also pay attention to which column you use to determine where the last row of data is. Your `UsedRange` property will include all the rows with formulas, but some of the other methods restrict the last row search to a single column.